# Apache Cassandra unrequired hint files present in hints folder

Tags: cassandra

On Apache Cassandra 3.11.1, during cassandra decommission I noticed that the node tries to send hints. I checked the hints folder and found hints that are very old or are present for already removed nodes. I decided to delete them so they are not part of the decommission process, but after decommissioning a node, the process fails and the node gets stuck in UL state.

Stacktrace:

```
ERROR [HintsDispatcher:3] 2022-12-12 17:58:39,364 CassandraDaemon.java:228 - Exception in thread Thread[HintsDispatcher:3,1,RMI Runtime]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/lib/cassandra/hints/xxxx-1670867104313-1.hints
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.ChannelProxy.openChannel(ChannelProxy.java:55) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.ChannelProxy.<init>(ChannelProxy.java:66) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.ChecksummedDataInput.open(ChecksummedDataInput.java:77) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsReader.open(HintsReader.java:78) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatcher.create(HintsDispatcher.java:73) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatchExecutor$DispatchHintsTask.deliver(HintsDispatchExecutor.java:273) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatchExecutor$DispatchHintsTask.dispatch(HintsDispatchExecutor.java:260) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatchExecutor$DispatchHintsTask.dispatch(HintsDispatchExecutor.java:238) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatchExecutor$DispatchHintsTask.run(HintsDispatchExecutor.java:217) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ConcurrentHashMap.java:3566) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatchExecutor$TransferHintsTask.transfer(HintsDispatchExecutor.java:186) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatchExecutor$TransferHintsTask.run(HintsDispatchExecutor.java:159) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:81) [apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/lib/cassandra/hints/0891d19f-7ba9-4fc6-973c-79f98253cf4e-1670867104313-1.hints
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:177) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.ChannelProxy.openChannel(ChannelProxy.java:51) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Final Error:

```
ERROR [RMI TCP Connection(350)-127.0.0.1] 2022-12-12 18:05:33,190 StorageService.java:3954 - Error while decommissioning node 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/lib/cassandra/hints/xxxx-1670867104313-1.hints
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.ChannelProxy.openChannel(ChannelProxy.java:55) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.ChannelProxy.<init>(ChannelProxy.java:66) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.ChecksummedDataInput.open(ChecksummedDataInput.java:77) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsReader.open(HintsReader.java:78) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatcher.create(HintsDispatcher.java:73) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatchExecutor$DispatchHintsTask.deliver(HintsDispatchExecutor.java:273) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatchExecutor$DispatchHintsTask.dispatch(HintsDispatchExecutor.java:260) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatchExecutor$DispatchHintsTask.dispatch(HintsDispatchExecutor.java:238) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatchExecutor$DispatchHintsTask.run(HintsDispatchExecutor.java:217) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ConcurrentHashMap.java:3566) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatchExecutor$TransferHintsTask.transfer(HintsDispatchExecutor.java:186) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatchExecutor$TransferHintsTask.run(HintsDispatchExecutor.java:159) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:81) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/lib/cassandra/hints/0891d19f-7ba9-4fc6-973c-79f98253cf4e-1670867104313-1.hints
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:177) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.ChannelProxy.openChannel(ChannelProxy.java:51) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
```

How can I avoid such a scenario?

I tried `nodetool truncatehints`, but it does nothing on the node.

Comment: What is the exact stacktrace when the decommission fails?

Comment: on a side note, `3.11.1` (released on 2018-05-04) is very old (4+ years) and [`3.11.14` is the latest in that 3.x series supported untill May/Jun 2023](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11.14/CHANGES.txt) which is current. Also, [`4.0.7` is the latest version](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/download.html) as of this writing.

Comment: @Madhavan
Shared the stacktrace.

Comment: For upgrading cassandra within 3.11, is there any complication to look out for?

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I would just run a `nodetool removenode` on it.  The `removenode` process will:

- get rid of a stuck `DL`/`UL` node.
- move data to its new token ranges from the other replicas.

> What happens in case all data was already migrated from the leaving node? will the removenode command then stream again and create duplicate data?

Yes, it streams it again, but it doesn’t create “duplicate data;” not in the same way that in-place writes do.

> So a cleanup will clear out this re-streamed data?

No.  The streaming happens at the SSTable file level.  So essentially a whole new file is being streamed during the decomm/remove process.  If there was already duplicate, in-place-updated data present, it still will be there on its new node.  If there was only a single write at the partition level, then that's all that will be there.  If it already exists, this process will simply write one file over another, and Cassandra will never know it was even there.

When you add or remove a node, a token range calculation is triggered.  This means that some nodes end up containing data that they are no longer responsible for (because another node now is).  Running a `nodetool cleanup` removes data which:

1. has already been streamed somewhere else.
2. remains on a node which
   will never use it.

Comment: What happens in case all data was already migrated from the leaving node? will the removenode command then stream again and create duplicate data?

Comment: @niagara11 Yes, it streams it again, but it doesn’t create “duplicate data;” not in the same way that in-place writes do.

Comment: So a cleanup will clear out this re-streamed data?

Comment: @niagara11 Edit made.